# VBA Web Automation: Trigger Return/Tab Event of Text Input

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer, dom

I am working with a website that I cannot mimic the behavior of in VBA.

When on the login page, after entering a password and tabbing or entering out, it enables the "Submit" button action. See below pictures and html. Notice the LoginAction comes from disabled to enabled (not disabled).

**Before Password Entry**
[image: Pic1]

**After Password Entry**
[image: Pic2]

The problem is I cannot mimic this behavior in VBA outside of using SendKeys.

After entering the password, I have tried the following to now avail.

```
doc.getElementById("btnLogin").disabled = False 'this does enable the button, but clicking it does nothing (even manually, because the built-in code/function was not triggered)
doc.parentWindow.execScript("loginAction()", "JavaScript")
doc.parentWindow.execScript("btnLogin()", "JavaScript")

========================================

doc.getElementById("password1").Focus
Dim theEvent As Object
Set theEvent = doc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
theEvent.initEvent "onenterclickbutton", True, False
doc.getElementById("password1").dispatchEvent theEvent
```

I have also played with focus and click and a few other things.

`SendKeys "{TAB}", True` works and I want to avoid for obvious reasons.

(if you need html pasted as text, lmk).

Comment: Is the website one we can play with even without a proper login? Or is it, I suspect, private? Side note: selenium basic usually works well in these cases. And have you altered the html to remove the disabled attribute | to match the second image html? And lastly, did you look at all the associated event listeners?

Comment: There are a number of ways you can capture those events via console e.g. [1](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/quickly-monitor-events-from-the-console-panel) as well as inspecting event-listeners tab in browser.

Comment: @QHarr - I found the answer was to set focus on input box then on another field to fire event.